# How to make jQuery accordion collapse?

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion

Here is the code :

```js
(function($) {

var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
allPanels.slideUp();
$(this).parent().next().slideDown();
return false;
});

})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/VPfJ5/3/

How do I make the accordion collapse the panel when clicked again?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
(function($) {

var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();

    if($(this).parent().next().is(':hidden'))
    {
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    }

    return false;
 });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler and *bulletproof* approach: [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VPfJ5/7537/)

```
var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function( e ) {
   e.preventDefault(); // don't use return false;
   allPanels.stop().slideUp();
   $(this).parent().next('dd').stop().slideToggle();
 });
```

The trick is to

- `slideUp` all panels
- but use `slideToggle` on the current one
- *bulletproof* thanks to the proper use of `.stop()`

<sub>P.S: Don't misuse `return false`, use the proper `event.preventDefault` instead.</sub>